# Obtaining nested resource id form URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, nested-resources

I have made a nested resources (as below). While being on a coffee_profile#show view, create a specific recipe for that one particular profile via link (/coffee_profiles/:coffee_profile_id/recipes/new(.:format)).

```
resources :coffee_profiles do 
  resources :recipes, only: [:new, :create, :show]
end
```

I wanted to catch coffee_profile_id that is present in URL for reference to which coffee_profile does the recipe belong and hide in in recipes#new form in hidden_field just to pass it with other parameters while submitting. 
 However, I don't know how to get that id itself, hidden_field creates this param, but it is populated with nil after submitting coffee_profile_id: ''

this is from recipes_controller.rb

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new 
end 

def create
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save
    flash[:success] = "Recipe created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:error] = @recipe.errors.inspect
    render :new
  end
end
```

And this is recipes#new form_for:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated and let me know if You need more info/code.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GqDK.png)

Comment: Hey! Please post the whole form!

Comment: And also: Can you submit any recipe at all or is it always nil? Post your recipe.rb and coffee_profile.rb model file as well.

Comment: Hey! Here is link to models and form. https://pastebin.com/ZDdFQDsr I actually cannot submit recipe currently. There is an error: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff0ffcf6230 ; @messages={:coffee_profile=>["must exist"]}, @details={:coffee_profile=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

Comment: Even if I create a new CoffeeProfile and from there I try to submit a recipe belonging to it, the same error pops out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using nested resources, somehow coffee_profile has to be present.

There is actually no need to store you recipe somewhere, because your recipe has a has_many and belongs_to relationship.

You need to change your form like so:

```
<%= form_for([@coffee_profile, Recipe.new]) do |f| %>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :coffee %>
      <%= f.text_field :coffee %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :quantity %>
      <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :method %>
      <%= f.text_field :method %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :water_temperature %>
      <%= f.number_field :water_temperature %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :water_amount %>
      <%= f.number_field :water_amount %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :grind %>
      <%= f.text_field :grind %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :aroma %>
      <%= f.text_field :aroma %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :aroma_points %>
      <%= f.number_field :aroma_points %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :taste %>
      <%= f.text_field :taste %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :taste_points %>
      <%= f.number_field :taste_points %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :body_points %>
      <%= f.number_field :body_points %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :astringency %>
      <%= f.text_field :astringency %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :astringency_points %>
      <%= f.number_field :astringency_points %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.label :brew_time %>
      <%= f.number_field :brew_time %>
    </div>
    <div class="recipes_form_item">
      <%= f.submit :Submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

now, inside your coffee_profile_controller, add in your new method (or wherever you render the form for your Recipe:

```
@coffee_profile = CoffeeProfile.find(params[:id])
```

Now, inside your recipe_controller add inside create:

```
@coffee_profile = CoffeeProfile.find(params[:id])
@recipe = @coffee_profile.recipes.create(recipe_params)

if @recipe.save
 redirect_to root_path
end
```

change also inside the new method everything like so:

def new
  @coffee_profile = CoffeeProfile.find(params[:id])
  @recipe = @coffee_profile.recipe.new
end

and for the recipe_params,
make sure that you are accepting `:coffee_profile_id`

```
params.require(:recipe).permit(:id, your other values and :coffee_profile_id)
```

Now, when you go to your console you can say: `@recipe = Recipe.last`

and then `@recipe.coffee_profile`, which will give you all information back about the coffee profile.

Greetings!

Comment: I did all the changes as you suggested (for form I had to add [] as it wanted those parameters in an array - it thrown can't write unknown attribute `html' error). All seems to work fine but when I submit there is an error in create method in recipes_controller.rb 'Couldn't find CoffeeProfile with 'id'. I can't figure out why, all params are permitted and it should be alright. Those are parts of controllers: https://pastebin.com/55cXz6kZ

Comment: Try to change it to:     @coffee_profile = CoffeeProfile.find(params[:coffee_profile_id]) instead inside the recipe controller.

Comment: If its still not working, please post the terminal log when you submit a new recipe in your original question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working, I have added the screen under <console log>.

Comment: And you submit your recipe from the coffee_profile show page, correct?

Comment: So i've made a quick example and uploaded it to my GitHub. You can find it here: https://github.com/Prometheus88/CoffeeRecipe and follows the exact same, simplified setup as yours and it works. Have a look at it.

Comment: That is correct - for example for 4th profile the URL is http://localhost:3000/coffee_profiles/4/recipes/new

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it actually worked when I changed params in new method in recipes_controller.rb from '@coffee_profile = CoffeeProfile.find(params[:id])' to '@coffee_profile = CoffeeProfile.find(params[:coffee_profile_id])' instead. Thank You very much for help! I really do appreciate.